# How to delete duplicate restored user files with "(2)" added (Win7)

Tags: windows-7

How to delete duplicate restored user files with "(2)" added (Win7)
I restored my user files on windows 7 system from the Win 7 backup.  I selected the wrong restore option and all files were restored.  Existing unchanged files were restored with the text string " (2)".

Is there a way to write a batchfile or script to do this operation?

Example file name:
"01 lesson 1"
"01 lesson 1 (2)"

I want to delete all files which had " (2)" appended on restore.

Comment: "Is there a way to write a batchfile or script to do this operation?"  Yes, there is, but we're not a script-writing service. What have you got so far? Where exactly are you getting stuck constructing your batch/script?  Alternatively, why not just do a `del "* (2).*"`?

Comment: Select the file then hit `delete`

Answer (score 0):

try

1)sort all files by date (right click on empty space inside a folder with that mess, and click "view->details" and "sort by->date modified") and see if this visually breaks down all files in 2 parts: old and new files - if it does the you can just select all (2), (3)... files and delete them yourself.

2)search for "(2)" files and delete them?

inside a folder with that mess type into search field "name: (2)" without quotes. after that delete all files that windows finds. the search field is located in the right upper corner. it says "*Search [folder name]*".

3)or you can try some duplicate file finder/remover apps: "Yet Another Duplicate File Remover":
http://sourceforge.net/projects/yadfr/

or "Duplicate Files Finder"
http://sourceforge.net/projects/doubles/

Comment: Thank you to all.  I will try the del commands and the software tools.  The problem is that every folder has double files. This includes all my music folders/files.  Doing it manually will take a lot of time.  I will also try "del *(2)* /s /q" - without the dot since most of the files end in just " (2)". 

I'm restoring my user directory from a Carbonite backup which does not have the (2) files added.  I can run the del command and if it destroys my home directory.

I'll reply with any updates on the commands and the software as it pertains to my problem.

Thanks,

Ed T.

Answer (score 0):

From a command prompt at the root of the drive or folder where the files were restored to:

`del *(2).* /s /q`